# How to add json object to arguments

Tags: json, powershell, cmd

I'm trying to add json object to my powershell script using cmd. My issue, is that I receive the string but without any quotes.

My script.ps1:

```
Write-Host ($args[0] | Format-Table | Out-String)
```

My command line :

```
C:\path\to\powershell.exe ./script.ps1 '{"key1":"val1","all":[{"key2":"val2","key3":"val3","key4":["val5","val6"]},{"key5":"val7","key6":"val8","key7":["val9","val10"]}],"key8":0}'
```

Result :

```
{key1:val1,all:[{key2:val2,key3:val3,key4:[val5,val6]},{key5:val7,key6:val8,key7:[val9,val10]}],key8:0}
```

How can I get my json with quotes ?

Comment: `$args[0] | ...` -> `$args[0] | ConvertFrom-Json | ...`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm getting the following error `ConvertFrom-Json : Primitive JSON non valide : OK.`

Comment: You might have to escape the quotation marks in the input, eg. `powershell.exe ./script.ps1 "'{""key1"":""val1""}'"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm trying to avoid this methods using escape, there is no other option ? I don't want to use json file too

Comment: You could read the json from a file (or perhaps request it directly from the source with `Invoke-WebRequest` if it's coming from an API), then you don't need to worry about escaping the command line

Comment: If you do not want to escape characters, then you should not try to pass arguments via one script interpreter to another. So if you're intent on using that method, you'd need to escape all of the nested doublequotes with backward slashes. Example: `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File ".\script.ps1" "{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"all\":[{\"key2\":\"val2\",\"key3\":\"val3\",\"key4\":[\"val5\",\"val6\"]},{\"key5\":\"val7\",\"key6\":\"val8\",\"key7\":[\"val9\",\"val10\"]}],\"key8\":0}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using **PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**, ***unescaped* `"` on the command line are *removed* during command-line parsing**, and only *then* is the result interpreted as PowerShell code to execute (due to the (implied) use of the `-Command` / `-c` parameter).<sup>[1]</sup>

You have two **options**:

- As [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) notes and demonstrates in his comment, **escaping all `"` chars. as `\"`** would work - the escaping ensures that they are *retained*, in unescaped form, and therefore become part of the PowerShell code to execute.
- If you want to **avoid escaping**, provide the **text *via the pipeline*** (stdin):

```
echo {"key1":"val1","all":[{"key2":"val2","key3":"val3","key4":["val5","val6"]},{"key5":"val7","key6":"val8","key7":["val9","val10"]}],"key8":0}| powershell.exe -c ./script.ps1 $input
```

Note the absence of a space before `|`, as such spaces would otherwise become part of the input.

In the PowerShell command, the piped-in text is accessed via the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input)

---

<sup>[1] It is for this reason that the outer `'...'` quoting does *not* protect the unescaped `"` inside it: During the initial parsing of the command line, `'` characters have *no* syntactic meaning.</sup>